# Raising a continued fraction to a power

Tags: binomial-theorem, continued-fractions

Is it possible to give a generalized formula for raising an continued fraction to a power? This is assuming that the continued fraction is in the form of
$$a_0+\frac{b_1}{a_1+\frac{b_2}{a_2+\ddots}}$$
I'd think first to the binomial expansion series, but even just with squaring, the fraction would divide itself up into trees. Is it even possible with a simple case, like $\phi ^2$, where
$$\phi=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\ddots}}$$
We can see that $\phi$ is the golden ratio $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ by simple numerical manipulation, showing us that $\phi ^2=(3+\sqrt{5})/2$. However, by squaring our continued fraction expansion, that much is certainly unclear. Will you help me?

Comment: I just had a look at the very complete [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction) : nothing similar to what you are looking for. Besides, a nice presentation of continued fractions can be found [here](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/ContinuedFractionsVI.pdf)

Comment: [The Power of Simple Continued Fractions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343934713_The_Power_of_Simple_Continued_Fractions).

Answer (score 5):

There has been a fair amount of work on continued fraction arithmetic, depending on what you want there are lots of options. It seems like Bill Gosper's multiplication algorithm is pretty close to what you want. This was discussed in an unpublished paper in 1972. There are some slides by Mark J. Dominus [here](https://perl.plover.com/yak/cftalk/) and this also provides a link to  [Gosper's version](https://perl.plover.com/classes/cftalk/INFO/gosper.txt). Liardet and Stambul also discussed questions on continued fraction arithmetic in [Algebraic Computations with Continued Fractions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X98922740) in 1996.

This list of work on this topic does not stop here and I can provide more references if required.